# Verified data retrieval from source with limited access

Tags: ftp, scripting

**Briefly:** I need to download data from a linux-based device, verify data integrity, and delete the source files (can't use rsync).

**Details:**
I have a hydrophone deployed at the bottom of the ocean as part of an ocean observatory. They hydrophone runs a [very] light RHEL-like linux distribution from the factory. The hydrophone generates a new .wav file every 5 minutes, and stores this on an SD card. The internal storage is small, so we would like to retrieve data using a cronjob/script running on an "retrieval machine" on shore, verify the files transferred completely, then delete the source files off of the hydrophone. My first thought was to use rsync, but the source does not permit rsync connections (see complications below).

**Complications:**

1. We do *not* have root or sudo privileges on the hydrophone.
2. The only protocols supported by the hydrophone are: scp, wget, FTP, ssh
3. rsync is not supported :(
4. Anonymous FTP is not allowed.
5. At the beginning of each 5-minute interval (e.g. 11:00, 11:05, ...) a file is created, at the end of the 5 minute interval (e.g. 11:04:59.999, 11:09:59.999 ...), the remainder of the file is written. This makes it impossible to just download all files and then delete all source files, because the file "stub" for the currently-recording 5 min files would also get deleted (the "stub" includes important metadata). Also note that when the file is initially written, it is written with the full (final) file size of 28MB, so I cannot just filter files based on file size.
   6) Occasionally, the 5-minute intervals get split into two files (with file sizes adding up to 28 MB total).
   7) The remote host (hydrophone) cannot run cronjobs, so most commands have to be passed through ssh.

Filenames are formatted as:
SBW_yyyymmdd_HHMMSS.wav

Thanks in advance for your help and answers, and please feel free to let me know if I can improve the clarity/detail of the question.

**UPDATE:**
After some tips in the comments below, and taking a rough stab at it, this is what I've come up with (I've generalized the result a bit). The script is run every 5 minutes as a cron job on our retrieval server. It is horribly slow and inefficient. Any input would be heplful!

```
#!/bin/bash
## Define Variables
remUser="<user>"           # Hydrophone SSH Username
remHost="<remote-host>"    # Hydrophone hostname   
sshCon="$remUser@$remHost"

## Remove previous md5 and get current MD5 Sums from remote-host
echo "Getting remoteWAV.md5 info"
rm -f remoteWAV.md5
ssh $sshCon 'cd ~/Data; md5sum *.wav' > remoteWAV.md5

## Check exit status and exit if bad connection
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then echo "Connection failed, aborting"; exit 1; fi

## Wait One minute for any changes to remote files
### This is to allow any in-progress files the chance
### to change their md5sum from the ones gathered earlier
echo "pausing 60 sec..."
sleep 60
echo "resuming..."

## Download the files
echo "Getting files from remote host"
scp $sshCon:~/Data/*.wav /path/to/local-data-files/
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then echo "Connection failed, aborting"; exit 1; fi

## Check the md5 sums
##    - First delete the old localWAV.md5 file
##    - Then we need to add the local directory to the filenames
##    - Now we can finally check the remote vs local checksums
echo "Checking local files against remoteWAV.md5 sums"
rm -f localWAV.md5
sed -i 's|SBW|/path/to/local-data-files/SBW|g' remoteWAV.md5
md5sum -c < remoteWAV.md5 > localWAV.md5

## Display checksum results
echo "Local MD5 results:"
echo "=================="
cat localWAV.md5

## Remove files that failed md5sum check from local storage
##    (This is so users don't download bad data)
cat localWAV.md5 | grep -v "OK" | cut -d ":" -f 1 | xargs -I {} rm -fv {}

## Find list of files that were downloaded successfully
##     - First remove the old goodfiles.tmp list
##     - Create a new listing of files that passed the md5sum check
##       but remove the last (most recent) file from the list in case
##       it is still being written on the remote host (second safety check)
##     - Remove the local directory from the filenames
##     - Copy the list of good files to the remote host
##     - Issue the delete command on the remote host
rm -f goodfilesWAV.tmp
head -n -1 localWAV.md5 | grep "OK" | cut -d ":" -f 1 > goodfilesWAV.tmp
sed -i 's|/path/to/local-data-files/||g' goodfilesWAV.tmp
echo "Sending deletion list to remote host"
scp ./goodfilesWAV.tmp $sshCon:~/Data/
echo "Removing files from remote host"
ssh $sshCon 'cd ~/Data; xargs rm -fv < goodfilesWAV.tmp; rm goodfilesWAV.tmp'
echo "Complete."
```

Comment: I would be very surprised if the device didn't have at least `md5sum` installed. Probably `sha1sum` and `sha256sum` as well. Also can you clarify whether you are able to ssh into the device?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I'll have to check on md5sum and the others - that would indeed make life easier. Though I am not hopeful, as it is the OS is very limited by the manufacturer. Edited the question: ssh is possible.

Comment: If you can ssh in, then you can probably run a simple shell script on the device, which would make it very easy. You defintely should look around and see what you have available in that environment.

Comment: What is the preferred language/interface that you want the code written in for the client?

Comment: @Michael Hampton: The device does not have cron or another way of having the script run automatically/recurring, so my understanding is that we will have to use a script remotely. But, it's all a moot point as I was informed this morning that our hydrophone has failed and isn't functional. I appreciate all of the help and will resume the thread when the repairs are made. In the mean time, let's discuss a solution that involves the retrieval and verification and I can test on a similar system.